# Questions with ended bounties are not being removed from the "featured" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, bountied-tab, expired-bounty

According to [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/300411), questions with bounties are removed from the "featured" tab once the bounty ends:

> Questions with an active bounty appear with a special icon in all question lists, and are also visible on the home page's Featured tab.
>
> During the grace period, there will be no indication in the questions lists (e.g. front page, featured tab) that the question has a bounty

However, the current behavior, at least in some instances, is that **bountied questions are remaining on the featured tab *beyond* the seven-day bounty period**.

On Biblical Hermeneutics.SE, a recently bountied question's [revision history](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/22824/revisions) shows that the bounty ended two days ago (July 26, 08:47 UTC) and that it started on July 18 at 07:00 UTC:

> [image: BH.SE example question]

Given this, the question should have been removed from the featured list on July 25, at the start of the grace period.  As of this moment, however, the question still appears on the featured tab:

> [image: BH.SE featured tab]

The problem is not limited to BH.SE.  On Christianity.SE right now [a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/50756/revisions) whose bounty was started more than 7 days ago, and which was already awarded, still appears in the featured tab:

> [image: C.SE example question]
>
> [image: C.SE featured tab]

Why are bountied questions not being removed from the featured tab exactly 7 days after their bounties start?

Comment: I also observed this in [Spanish L&U](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured). I awarded a bounty yesterday and the question is still featured.

Comment: The funny thing is that the question showed as featured until just now, when a new bounty was started.

Comment: @fedorqui Agreed, this is a consistent pattern: the question remains featured until a new bounty is started whereupon it falls off.

Comment: Reproduced on Workplace, see this duplicate: [Why does the Workplace's featured question tab show a question without a bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283173/)

Comment: More info: if there are others bounties offered, the question disappears from featured as soon as the bounty gets awarded. At least this happened [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17437/1674).

Comment: Confirmed on Workplace: the second a new bounty is started, the old question disappears from the tab.

Comment: I've also experienced the issue on Hinduism.SE

Comment: Well, it's clearly a cross network bug, on each and every of the 150+ sites.

Comment: Fully reproducible: I recently awarded a bounty on [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/73874) and it's still in the Featured tab. Seems like this cycle won't ever end and as @ShadowWizard mentioned all sites seem to be affected, though of course it will only be visible on the ones that don't constantly have active bounties

Comment: Reproduced on German.SE, Philosophy.SE, Astronomy.SE, Space.SE and Law.SE. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283404/questions-with-bounties-that-were-awarded-long-ago-show-up-on-the-featured-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Reproduced on Retrocomputing.SE http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured

Comment: Sites are being taken down for maintenance. Maybe it's being fixed? :hopeful:

Comment: @wizzwizz4 nope. Sometimes bugs are left for years when they don't have critical impact.

Comment: @Nathaniel You've hand-drawn-circled around the wrong "occured yesterday" on both pictures: that's the "notice removed", not the "end of bounty" notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as explained by Marc Gravell in [his post](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/248/621) on Retrocomputing Meta, this has been fixed.

> it was everywhere, but it would only be observed if there was a site
>   with an index that was changing from non-empty to empty, most commonly
>   because the last "featured" question expired or was awarded. That
>   means we wouldn't expect to see it on sites like stackoverflow,
>   because that just would never happen

> Thanks; there was a bug on the "tag engine" (the backend system that
>   deals with this stuff) that failed to update the "count" of an index
>   when that index was being reduced to zero (it is fine when reducing in
>   general - just the zero case is the problem). This meant it was
>   happily reporting data that it *knew* wasn't "featured" (or
>   whatevever) any more. Essentially (not the actual code!):
>
> ```
> // rebuild a filtered+sorted index...
> int matches = workspace.ApplyFilter();
> if(matches == 0) {
>      // nothing to do
> } else {
>     workspace.ApplySort();
>     index.UpdateCountAndCopyFromWorkspace(matches , workspace);
> }
> ```
>
> In the zero case, it would never actually mark the index as being
>   empty (the "nothing to do" was wrong - it should still have updated
>   the count). Entirely my fault. A permanent fix for this will deploy
>   today.

Comment: Yeah, same thing. I found the bug on 4 meta sites, but missed it here.