# Why does the Workplace's featured question tab show a question without a bounty?

Tags: bug, bountied-tab

The Workplace [featured question tab](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) is currently displaying [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71937/how-do-i-ask-a-recruiter-for-time-to-update-my-resume), which doesn't actually have a bounty. It does have an awarded bounty but I can see no other reason behind it suddenly reappearing in the tab.

Two users on chat [confirmed seeing the same thing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31556976#31556976).

### Feature Question Tab

[image: tab]

### Question

[image: question]

### History

[image]

---

EDIT: [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281760/questions-with-ended-bounties-are-not-being-removed-from-the-featured-tab?rq=1) seems to cover the same bug, but I'm not sure if the featured listing persisted or reappeared, though I suppose the former is more likely.

EDIT2: As mentioned on the linked question, the question was removed from this tab the second another bounty was started.

EDIT3: Reproducible: I recently awarded [this bounty](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/73874/how-do-i-manage-the-expectation-of-detail-orientation-at-work/73923#73923) and [the question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/73874/how-do-i-manage-the-expectation-of-detail-orientation-at-work) is still in the Featured tab.