# Questions with bounties that were awarded long ago show up on the featured tab

Tags: bug, bounties

Questions with bounties that were awarded long ago (> 1 week) show up on the featured tab on several sites. All instances I've seen so far are on sites where this is the only item in the featured tab.

For example, on [German.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured):

[image]

Note that there is no blue [+n] before the question. Also, the bounty was already awarded to an answer on the 11th of August. If an bounty was started after that, it wouldn't have expired yet, but it has also not been awarded.

This is also on [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured), [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), [Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) and [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured). In all cases, the bounty has been awarded and its the only featured question in the tab.