# Community sidebar isn't updating featured list

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, caching, bountied-tab, featured-tag

About 19 hours ago, I [edited the featured tag out of a question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/5206/revisions) and into another. About 7 hours ago, I made a few other small changes. The sidebar still hasn't updated to list the new questions.

I'd normally just blame caching, but the sidebar cache expires after four or six hours, so it definitely should have refreshed by now.

I'm getting antsy for someone to blame for all the horrible things in the world. Does anyone know what's up with sidebar refreshes?

Comment: For reference, this is on [puzzling.se].

Comment: @hichris Good point; I've edited in a link to the post in question.

Comment: The [featured tab is buggy for a while now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281760/questions-with-ended-bounties-are-not-being-removed-from-the-featured-tab), I'm almost sure this is the same bug. Something behind the scenes fails to update the tab. Hopefully as we find more bugs with it, someone from the team will notice.